# Zend Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db, mysql-error-1054

I have a next code:

```
    $parent_priority = $data['priority'];
    $where = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('priority >= ?', $parent_priority);
    $columns = array ('id',
                      'title',
                      'enabled',
                      'description',
                      'pv',
                      'gv',
                      'mps', 'priority',
                      );
    $select_data = $this->select()->from($this->_name, $columns);
    $ranks = $this->fetchAll($select_data)->toArray();
```

But Zend create an error "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'" in line `$ranks = $this->fetchAll($select_data)->toArray();`

How I can solve this?

Comment: Is there any way you can get the generated SQL?

Comment: Yes. But I should use a Zend appotunities.

Comment: No, I mean to view the SQL that's actually being sent to the server so you can try to deduce what went wrong (and hence give you a place to look for debugging)...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just suppress the last "," from your array after 'priority'.